# Resolve the error in Getting user input in Oracle Apex DB

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RegEvent
AS
    Attender Attendee%rowtype;
    
BEGIN

    dbms_output.enable;
    --set prompt
    ACCEPT namee char prompt 'Enter your Name:  ';
    ACCEPT Attender_id char prompt 'Enter your id:  ';
    ACCEPT Attender_mail char prompt 'Enter your E-Mail:  ';
    ACCEPT Attender_phone char prompt 'Enter your Phone No:  ';
    ACCEPT Att_event prompt char 'Enter the event ID:  ';

    --Get Values

    namee := '&namee';
    Attender_Mail := '&Attender_Mail';
    Attender_phone := '&Attender_phone';

    dbms_output.put_line('Choose any id for future reference:  ');
    Att_event := '&Att_event';

    dbms_output.put_line('Enter the event want to register:  ');
    Attender_id := '&Attender_id';

    Attender.Attendee_name := namee;
    Attender.Attendee_mail := Attender_Mail;
    Attender.Attendee_phone := Attender_phone;
    Attender.Event_id := Att_event;
    Attender.Attendee_id := Attender_id;
    
    --Insert Table
    INSERT INTO
    attendee
    VALUES Attender;
    --Save Changes
    COMMIT;

END RegEvent;
```

it shows

```
Error at line 9: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NAMEE" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;



7.     --set prompt
8.     ACCEPT namee char prompt 'Enter your Name:  ';
9.     ACCEPT Attender_id char prompt 'Enter your id:  ';
10.     ACCEPT Attender_mail char prompt 'Enter your E-Mail:  ';
11.     ACCEPT Attender_phone char prompt 'Enter your Phone No:  ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Huh, that's quite a mess you posted, mixture of SQL Plus, anonymous PL/SQL block which can't be salvaged.

You can't put SQL Plus commands into PL/SQL procedure; use them out of it. Also, you tagged the question with Apex tag; SQL Plus commands won't work there (it'll report `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement` if you try to use `accept`).

Here's how it works in SQL Plus.

Sample table first:

```
SQL> create table attendee
  2    (name   varchar2(10),
  3     id     number,
  4     mail   varchar2(20),
  5     phone  varchar2(10),
  6     event  number);

Table created.
```

Procedure accepts parameters whose values are then inserted into the target table:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure regevent
  2    (par_name  in attendee.name%type,
  3     par_id    in attendee.id%type,
  4     par_mail  in attendee.mail%type,
  5     par_phone in attendee.phone%type,
  6     par_event in attendee.event%type
  7    )
  8  is
  9  begin
 10    insert into attendee (name, id, mail, phone, event)
 11      values (par_name, par_id, par_mail, par_phone, par_event);
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.
```

Get values:

```
SQL> ACCEPT par_name  char prompt 'Enter your Name:  ';
Enter your Name:  Little
SQL> ACCEPT par_id    char prompt 'Enter your id:  ';
Enter your id:  123
SQL> ACCEPT par_mail  char prompt 'Enter your E-Mail:  ';
Enter your E-Mail:  lf@gmail.com
SQL> ACCEPT par_phone char prompt 'Enter your Phone No:  ';
Enter your Phone No:  123-456
SQL> ACCEPT par_event char prompt 'Enter the event ID:  ';
Enter the event ID:  5588
SQL>
```

Call the procedure by providing values of substitution variables; pay attention to single quotes usage (around `varchar2` values):

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL> begin
  2    regevent('&par_name', &par_id, '&par_mail', '&par_phone', &par_event);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from attendee;

NAME               ID MAIL                 PHONE           EVENT
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
Little            123 lf@gmail.com         123-456          5588

SQL>
```

---

If you use Apex, why don't you create combination of Interactive Report (to view values in that table) and Form (to insert/edit values)? That's what Apex is *best* used for.

If you insist on its SQL Workshop, then create a procedure and call it by providing values *instantly*, without asking user (actually, yourself - no end user will ever see SQL Workshop) to provide values:

```
SQL> begin
  2    regevent('Foot', 421, 'foot@yahoo.com', '9887-23', 43);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From attendee;

NAME               ID MAIL                 PHONE           EVENT
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
Little            123 lf@gmail.com         123-456          5588
Foot              421 foot@yahoo.com       9887-23            43

SQL>
```